# Helmchart install status is success but no pods are deployed

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes-helm

Getting HTTP 404 not found when helm install is accessing (below mentioned paths) , these http calls are made during execution of command `helm install connected-context ./connected-context2 -v=6` , command is executed on **windows machine** , using **docker desktop** and **minikube**.

1. "GET [https://127.0.0.1:63746/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/connected-context-app-conf"](https://127.0.0.1:63746/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/connected-context-app-conf%22)
2. "GET [https://127.0.0.1:63746/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/connected-context-opsinsight-rule-engine"](https://127.0.0.1:63746/apis/sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2/namespaces/default/sparkapplications/connected-context-opsinsight-rule-engine%22)

Output status of command is DEPLOYED but no relevant pods are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look in all namespaces?

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Maybe you can provide more information (your helm templates). Otherwise, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but the isse was something else unrelated for 404 not found .

Comment: having the same issue, helm is happy, release successful, nothing there - in any namespace